# How to find the amount of time it takes for the request to be sent from Jmeter to the server

Tags: jmeter

I am designing a load test scenario in which jmeter is interacting with some back end services.
I have executed the script and I've gone through view results in table and Aggregate report. What I wanted to understand is do we have a way to find out the the amount of time it takes for the request to reach the server from my local instance of Jmeter.
Is that latency or something else ?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter exposes the following [metrics](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html):

1. Connect Time: time to establish the connection with the server
2. Latency: time from sending the request till receiving the first byte of the response ([TTFB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_first_byte))
3. Elapsed Time: Latency + time to get the last byte of the response ([TTLB](https://www.dareboost.com/en/doc/website-speed-test/metrics/time-to-last-byte-ttlb))

The time to reach the server can be obtained only from server logs, the maximum you can get from JMeter is [increasing logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/) so you can get timestamps for each HTTP event

[image]

This can be achieved by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" />
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick up the change

Comment: On my side the HTTP Request JMeter element does not have the log at all. How could I enable it?